# Docker py how to access from a container the Docker Host with from_env()

Tags: python, docker

I am inside a container and I'd like to grab a container from the Docker machine/host. I would have usually done this from my local machine, but via the docker container it gives me an error:

```
client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.get('myPostgres')
```

Spits out:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Comment: That looks more like you're using an older or different version of the Python `docker` module or something in which `docker.client.DockerClient.containers` is a function rather than an attribute. What does `client.containers()` return? How did you install the `docker` module?

Comment: Hi! client.containers() returns the next:

"requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))"

Comment: Ps. Yes, I "pip install docker"

Comment: Is the docker socket (`/var/run/docker.sock`) exposed inside the container? What was your `docker run` command line?

Comment: Hi, no! This was my docker run: docker run -d -i --name my_python_container python bash

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A container by default will not have any access to the host Docker service (this is a security feature: access to docker is synonymous with `root` access, so you only want to expose this access in specific situations).

If you want to access your host's Docker service from inside a container, you need to map the Docker socket into the container. Generally, this means running something like:

```
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...
```

Compare:

```
$ docker run --rm -it docker.io/python:3.10 bash
$ pip install docker
[...]
$ python
root@2dfed359374e:/# python
Python 3.10.3 (main, Mar 18 2022, 16:01:59) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
>>> c = docker.from_env()
Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

With this:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock docker.io/python:3.10 bash
root@ebe430bc9463:/# pip install docker
[...]
root@ebe430bc9463:/# python
Python 3.10.3 (main, Mar 18 2022, 16:01:59) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import docker
>>> c = docker.from_env()
>>> c.containers.list()
[<Container: ebe430bc94>, <Container: 91f24628fd>]
```

Comment: Is this recommended?

Comment: @maltoze I think the opening paragraph of the answer may address that question. If you're running something that requires access to the Docker API in order to function (e.g., [Traefik](https://traefik.io/)), then this is how you do it.